# Cordova: Publisher attribute of the Identity Error

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I am trying to create package for windows phone. In Visual Studio I select `Store -> Associate App with the Store...`. Association runs OK. Then I select `Store -> Create App Packages...` and I am getting error:

```
The Publisher attribute of the Identity element in the app manifest must have the value of the Publisher ID value from your developer account: CN=<app-cn-value>. G:\path-to-manifest\package.windows80.appxmanifest
```

When I look in `.appxmanifest` file and the value is as it should be:

```
 Publisher="CN=<app-cn-value>"
```

How should I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the screenshot of the temp certificate (that is created when Associating app) properties: [image]

Is it OK that publisher is "Apache Cordova Team"?

**UPDATE 2:**
As I wasn't successful with visual studio, I tried to create package via CLI. When setting package identity name (attribute `id` in tag `widget` in `config.xml`) and building (`cordova build windows --release`) project I am getting error:

```
G:\path-to-project\windows\build\windows\release\anycpu\AppxManifest.xml(24,18): error APPX1404: File content does not confor
m to specified schema. The 'Id' attribute is invalid - The value '7XXXXXXX.Name' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ap
px/2010/manifest:ST_ApplicationId' - The Pattern constraint failed. [G:\path-to-project\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows.jsproj]
```

Looks like that build fails because `Id` value starts with number. If I put a letter (`a`) in front of `Id` value, then build is successful, but when uploading the package analysis is unsuccessful (as expected):

```
Invalid package identity name: a7XXXXXXX.Name (expected: 7XXXXXXX.Name)
```

Why does not cordova build app with that kind of package id?

Comment: Did you find a solution to properly set Package Identity Name from Cordova?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late but I ran into the same problem and identified two potential causes :

- If your cordova-windows lib is older than 4.1.0, maybe your facing this issue : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8856
- Otherwise, I found out that the cordova "prepare" task was updating the .appxmanifest files as well, and they introduced a WindowsStoreIdentityName preference to prevent the task from setting an invalid identity name.

The latter is not well documented yet, but if you add :

```
<preference name="WindowsStoreIdentityName" value="7XXXXXXX.Name" />
```

to your config.xml file, it might just fix your build error. It did for me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<app-cn-value>` with your ID , you can get your ID from:

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/Account/Management ,

```
Windows publisher ID

CN= YOUR CN HERE
```

**UPDATE :**

This guy have a solution for this problem :

> by unloading the project in Visual Studio, editing the project file
>   and commenting out the following line: . Alternatively if it's ok
>   for you, you can delete the Package.StoreAssociation.xml in Solution
>   Explorer as well

http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/metro/windowsstore.aspx?ID=02131f39-1db4-448c-9eb4-3aeea6b2aca7

If that didn't work, **please try to restart the Visual Studio and associate your app with the Store again ..**

**UPDATE :**

A lot of devs reported that is working !

Ref : http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/metro/windowsstore.aspx?ID=d4254563-5e39-4ea5-9b79-13533709d91f

**UPDATE 3 :**

Please see this from Cordova .. this is about packaging for Windows :

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide/platforms/win8/packaging.html

Comment: Nasser, I am using ID. <app-cn-value> was just for example

Comment: I'm not sure why, but have you tried to restart the VS and re associate your app with the store ?

Comment: Tried to restart VS, restart computer, unload/reload project, nothing :/

Comment: I've updated my answer, please try to follow it, if it doesn't working .. try to back-up your pfx file then associate with Windows Store .

Comment: Thx for update but I am stil not making any progress. I've update my question.